# Multi-texturing error in a game

Tags: windows-7, windows, gaming, hardware-acceleration

While trying to play a game, it gives error:

> This program requires multi-texturing, which is not supported by your hardware.

I have Dell D630 Laptop (with Windows 7 32-bit), I can remember this game used to work fine previously without above error.

Can anybody suggest what I am missing or any required software/library that needs to be installed for this to work?

Comment: Which game? SInce it worked fine before, what have you done since? Updated the drivers? Reinstalled the OS?

Comment: Has the game been upgraded since the last time you used it?

Comment: @mdpc: Nope it is the same one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your graphics drivers are missing.

1. Go to [Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1?c=uk&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1&l=en)
2. Enter your service tag number.
3. Download "video" drivers for your laptop
4. Install.

Hopefully Dell have the correct details for your laptop.

Comment: But display is working fine. Driver was already installed fine automatically with Windows 7 installation ?

Comment: There are both 2D and 3D drivers and one working does not mean the other definitely will, it could be that something has corrupted your 3D drivers, or some program is preventing your graphics from using 3D.  If rebooting doesn't work, try reinstalling, if that doesn't work then use System Restore to go back a week or so (may loose you some data) to when it should have worked.

Comment: Just updated the driver to resolve it. Thanks :)